# Como puedo generar una animacion en login con transiciones?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Estoy intentando copiar el  efecto de una animación como la que adjunto en el [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAtFBHNpfz0&feature=youtu.be) que hace que cuando sube el recuadro verde hace un efecto de transición que logro saber como se llama.

Adjunto el código de lo que fui armando [Codigo del login](https://jsbin.com/likulij/edit?css,js,output).

```js
document.querySelector('#verde').classList.toggle('en-colapso');
document.querySelector('.img__btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.cont').classList.toggle('s--signup');
  document.querySelector('#verde').classList.toggle('en-colapso');
  document.querySelector('#rojo').classList.toggle('en-colapso');
});
document.querySelector('.atras').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.cont').classList.toggle('s--signup');
  var espera = setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('#verde').classList.toggle('en-colapso');
    document.querySelector('#rojo').classList.toggle('en-colapso');
    clearTimeout('espera');
  }, 900);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

#rojo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}

#rojo h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#verde {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  background: rgb(2, 57, 130);
  background: linear-gradient(229deg, rgba(2, 57, 130, 1) 0%, rgba(36, 112, 150, 1) 14%, rgba(66, 160, 168, 1) 47%, rgba(88, 195, 181, 1) 90%);
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 23em;*/
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

#verdeRegi {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  background: rgb(2, 57, 130);
  background: linear-gradient(229deg, rgba(2, 57, 130, 1) 0%, rgba(36, 112, 150, 1) 14%, rgba(66, 160, 168, 1) 47%, rgba(88, 195, 181, 1) 90%);
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 23em;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-blurred-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1000px) scaleY(2.5) scaleX(0.2);
    transform: translateY(1000px) scaleY(2.5) scaleX(0.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(40px);
    filter: blur(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in-blurred-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1000px) scaleY(2.5) scaleX(0.2);
    transform: translateY(1000px) scaleY(2.5) scaleX(0.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(40px);
    filter: blur(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img__btn {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img__btn span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
}

.img__btn span.m--in {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-800px);
  transform: translateY(-800px);
}

.cont.s--signup .img__btn span.m--in {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.cont.s--signup .img__btn span.m--up {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(800px);
  transform: translateY(800px);
}

.cont.s--signup .img:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(640px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(640px, 0, 0);
}

.cont.s--signup .img__text.m--up {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
  transform: translateY(-1000px);
}

.img__text.m--in {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
  transform: translateY(-1000px);
}

.cont.s--signup .img__text.m--in {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.cont.s--signup .sign-in {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -393%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -393%, 0);
}

.cont.s--signup .sign-up {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
}

.cont.s--signup .sub-cont {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -1800px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0px, -1800px, 0)
}

.sign-in {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.sign-up {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  -webkit-animation: slide-in-blurred-bottom 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
  animation: slide-in-blurred-bottom 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
}

.sub-cont {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.img__text {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.img__text h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.img__text p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.en-colapso {
  display: none!important;
  z-index: 0
}

.atras {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cont">
    <div id="rojo" class="sign-up en-colapso h-100">
      <div id="verdeRegi">
        <div class="col-6 float-left">
          <span class="atras">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 float-right">
          <a href=" ">
            <svg class="float-right" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="55" height="55" viewBox="0 0 55 55">
              <defs>
                <path id="prefix__a" d="M0 0.274L54.727 0.274 54.727 55 0 55z"/>
                <path id="prefix__c" d="M0 55L54.727 55 54.727 0.274 0 0.274z"/>
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
              <path fill="#FFF" d="M7.857 20.952L11.213 20.952 11.213 32.622 16.369 32.622 16.369 35.357 7.857 35.357zM22.78 35.482l-.003-14.714h3.887l3.057 5.393c.873 1.551 1.724 3.384 2.402 5.044h.044c-.198-1.943-.264-3.929-.264-6.157v-4.28h3.058v14.714h-3.493l-3.145-5.674c-.873-1.594-1.855-3.472-2.553-5.197h-.088c.11 1.966.152 4.04.152 6.441v4.43h-3.055"/>
              <mask id="prefix__b" fill="#fff">
                <use xlink:href="#prefix__a"/>
              </mask>
              <path fill="#FFF" d="M27.365.274C12.252.274 0 12.525 0 27.64 0 42.749 12.252 55 27.365 55c15.112 0 27.362-12.251 27.362-27.361 0-15.114-12.25-27.365-27.362-27.365m0 51.404c-13.28 0-24.043-10.764-24.043-24.04 0-13.277 10.764-24.041 24.043-24.041 8.795 0 16.485 4.726 20.675 11.776L41.052 25.66c-.35.524-.7 1.048-1.027 1.616h-.044v-6.508h-3.298v14.714h3.298v-4.8l1.244-1.551 3.625 6.351h3.865l-5.11-8.447 6.218-7.976c1.02 2.665 1.583 5.556 1.583 8.58 0 13.275-10.764 24.039-24.041 24.039" mask="url(#prefix__b)"/>
              <mask id="prefix__d" fill="#fff">
                <use xlink:href="#prefix__c"/>
              </mask>
              <path fill="#FFF" d="M17.748 35.482L21.112 35.482 21.112 20.774 17.748 20.774zM21.604 16.424c0 1.2-.973 2.174-2.174 2.174-1.2 0-2.173-.973-2.173-2.174 0-1.2.974-2.173 2.173-2.173 1.2 0 2.174.973 2.174 2.173" mask="url(#prefix__d)"/>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="div container row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center " style=" right: 0; left: 0;">
        <div class="" style=" width: 100%;margin: auto;position: absolute;left: 0; right: 0;">
          <h1>Registrate</h1>
          <div class="col-12">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-cont ">
      <div class="">
        <div class="col-12">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="115" height="115" viewBox="0 0 55 55">
            <defs>
              <path id="prefix__a" d="M0 0.274L54.727 0.274 54.727 55 0 55z"/>
              <path id="prefix__c" d="M0 55L54.727 55 54.727 0.274 0 0.274z"/>
            </defs>
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
              <path fill="#FFF" d="M7.857 20.952L11.213 20.952 11.213 32.622 16.369 32.622 16.369 35.357 7.857 35.357zM22.78 35.482l-.003-14.714h3.887l3.057 5.393c.873 1.551 1.724 3.384 2.402 5.044h.044c-.198-1.943-.264-3.929-.264-6.157v-4.28h3.058v14.714h-3.493l-3.145-5.674c-.873-1.594-1.855-3.472-2.553-5.197h-.088c.11 1.966.152 4.04.152 6.441v4.43h-3.055"/>
              <mask id="prefix__b" fill="#fff">
                <use xlink:href="#prefix__a"/>
              </mask>
              <path fill="#FFF" d="M27.365.274C12.252.274 0 12.525 0 27.64 0 42.749 12.252 55 27.365 55c15.112 0 27.362-12.251 27.362-27.361 0-15.114-12.25-27.365-27.362-27.365m0 51.404c-13.28 0-24.043-10.764-24.043-24.04 0-13.277 10.764-24.041 24.043-24.041 8.795 0 16.485 4.726 20.675 11.776L41.052 25.66c-.35.524-.7 1.048-1.027 1.616h-.044v-6.508h-3.298v14.714h3.298v-4.8l1.244-1.551 3.625 6.351h3.865l-5.11-8.447 6.218-7.976c1.02 2.665 1.583 5.556 1.583 8.58 0 13.275-10.764 24.039-24.041 24.039" mask="url(#prefix__b)"/>
              <mask id="prefix__d" fill="#fff">
                <use xlink:href="#prefix__c"/>
              </mask>
              <path fill="#FFF" d="M17.748 35.482L21.112 35.482 21.112 20.774 17.748 20.774zM21.604 16.424c0 1.2-.973 2.174-2.174 2.174-1.2 0-2.173-.973-2.173-2.174 0-1.2.974-2.173 2.173-2.173 1.2 0 2.174.973 2.174 2.173" mask="url(#prefix__d)"/>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <h1>Ingresá </h1>
          <h2>a tu Home Banking</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 ">
          <form class="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Usuario</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Contaseña</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 float-left pl-0">
              <a href="">Teclado Virtual</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 float-right pr-0">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="verde" class="sign-in en-colapso">
        <div class="img__text m--up">
          <h2>¿Ya tenés usuario?</h2>
          <p>Sign up and discover great amount of new opportunities!</p>
          <div class="img__btn">
            <span class="m--up">Sign Up</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/56a8363fcc.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola compañero MaryAndy, por lineamientos de la comunidad temo decirte que tu pregunta no es una pregunta valida,y posiblemente termine cerrada a menos que la edites, para que la pregunta sea valida debe de contener dos cosas, un ejemplo minimo y verificable y que la pregunta no sea basada en opiniones, de lo contrario puede terminar cerrada, te recomiendo que la reformules.

Comment: Oka gracias @Riven si pasa que el ejemplo lo quise poner aca pero no me dejaba.

Comment: Hola, esta es la misma pregunta, y parece que eres el mismo usuario: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/335431/
 - Si necesitas unir las dos cuentas puedes ir acá: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: oka gracias @JheymanMejia